# Uploading file Webservice

Tags: django

I'm trying to upload a file into my web service (written using DJango REST framework). I have written the following code but I get data can not be converted to utf-8 error

```
with open('/images/img.jpg', 'rb') as imgFile:
            content = imgFile.read ()
        json = { 'fileName': 'img.jpg', 'img': content}
        json_data = simplejson.dumps(json)
        reqURL = urllib2.Request("http://localhost:8000/uploadfile/",json_data)
        opener = urllib2.build_opener()
        f = opener.open(reqURL)
```

What is the right way of passing file content over JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't send files like this. File contents are sent by embedding them inside the request body.

You may be better of by using the beautiful [**python-request**](http://www.python-requests.org/) library. Check out the [file upload section](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file).